# Get date string from the folder path using C#

Tags: c#, .net, directory

I am having a `List<string>` folder paths. The folder path is like  `root/input/YYYY/MM/DD/filename.txt`. Now I want to pick up *only the date* section(`YYYY/MM/DD`) from this path text in the list. Need some guidance on this. Thanks

```
List<string> lstPaths = new List<string>() {
  "root/input/2023/03/10/filename1.txt",
  "root/output/2023/03/14/filename2.txt",
}
```

Comment: a simple regEx can help you with that - try `"\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}"` (you might need to escape the `/` char, it's been a long time since I've used regEx and didn't test this before posting this comment

Comment: @Zohar Peled: Regular expression can do but if 1. We don't have false positives like `c:/1234/56/78/MyFolder/2023/03/14/filename1.txt` - in this case `1234`, `56` and `78` will be returned. 2. If we guarantee that `/` is used only; please, note that `@"root\input/2023\03\10\filename1.txt"` is a legal path as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `Regex` pattern will help you.

```
var pattern = @"\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}";
```

And check it using `Regex.Match()`

```
var dates = lstPaths.Select(p => Regex.Match(p, pattern).Value).ToList();
```

Comment: The problem with your approach is that you can have *false positive*: `c:/MyData/1234/56/78/MyFolder/2023/03/14/filename2.txt`: you'll get erroneous `1234`, `56` and `78`. Another problem is that we can use *both* `/` and `\\` as a directory delimiters: `c:/myfile.txt` and `c:\myfile.txt` are both valid

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes, but will work for paths that author provided. If he needs to use for  different kind of path, I think yes, `DirectoryInfo`  is better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `DirectoryInfo` for this:

```
using System.IO;

...
string path = "root/output/2023/03/14/filename2.txt";

...

DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path)?.Parent;

if (int.TryParse(dir?.Name, out int day) &&
    int.TryParse(dir?.Parent?.Name, out int month) &&
    int.TryParse(dir?.Parent?.Parent?.Name, out int year)) {
  // Relevant code for year, month, day 
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4C7w1N)

Comment: It's worth noting this solution will only work if the directory tree and file actually exist on the local filesystem.

Comment: @John Wu: no, `DirectoryInfo` just *parses* the given string whether file actually exists or not (I've check it on my workstation: it does work even if I don't have such a file). Please, fiddle yourself: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4C7w1N

Answer (score 1):

My solution works with the assumption that the path format ends with the "date"/"file" format and the date is always composed from 10 chars:

```
  var res = lstPaths.ConvertAll(x =>DateTime.Parse(x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf('/')-10,10)));
```

Comment: What does *magic number* `10` stand for, please?

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko - length of the date... is always the same if paths were defined in the consistent way to put 03 instead of 3 for months as an example.

Comment: Please note, that the current code is *too brittle* IMHO: it depends on current culture format for dates: what if I use "d/M/yyyy" format? It doesn't accept '\' directory delimiter. (`Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar` and `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` are actual delimiters)

Comment: In the request it mention the format YYYY/MM/DD so my solution is strictly for this question and not for other general formats

Comment: @D A: what if I have a valid path `"root/input/2023/03/10/filename1.txt"`, *but* my default datetime format is `d/M/yyyy`?

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko - sure, there are no good solutions with so many assumptions when we don't know the right context. We offer answers based on what we have and they will pick what is appropriate for their needs.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated @AVTUNEY 's answer to filter valid dates.
No idea what performs best. But this works and filters valid dates.

```
var pattern = @"\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}";

var p = "C:/MyData/1234/56/78/MyFolder/2023/03/14/filename2.txt";

var dates = Regex.Matches(p, pattern)
.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList()
.Where(e => DateTime.TryParse(e, out DateTime temp)).ToList();
```